# I need to write a query to show these information below

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Write a query to show the highest hourly rate, the lowest hourly rate and the average hourly for charges applicable. Name The columns Highest Rate, Lowest Rate, Average Rate, respectively. Formate all the columns to show dollars sign and 2 decimal spaces $99.99.

But for some reason when i this script:

```
COLUMN MAX(hourlyrate) FORMAT $99.99
COLUMN MIN(hourlyrate) FORMAT $99.99
COLUMN AVG(hourlyrate) FORMAT $99.99

SELECT MAX(hourlyrate) "Highest Rate",
       MIN(hourlyrate) "Lowest Rate",
       AVG(hourlyrate) "Average Rate respectively"
FROM charges;
```

It does not format the column with $99.99

Answer (score 1):

The column headings returned by your query do not match those defined in the sqlplus `FORMAT` commands.

You probably want:

```
COLUMN "Highest Rate" FORMAT $99.99
COLUMN "Lowest Rate" FORMAT $99.99
COLUMN "Average Rate respectively" FORMAT $99.99

SELECT MAX(hourlyrate) "Highest Rate",
       MIN(hourlyrate) "Lowest Rate",
       AVG(hourlyrate) "Average Rate respectively"
FROM charges;
```